# Having trouble trying to clear out an image previously created using Javascript

Tags: javascript

With a button click, I am adding an image to a div titled 'floatingButton1'. Later on, I want to run a separate function and remove the image I added so that the background image can be seen.

Here is my code to add the image.

```
var floatingButton1 = document.getElementById('floatingButton1');
    var i1 = document.createElement("img");
    i1.src = "Images/tnR1.png";
    i1.type = "image";
    floatingButton1.appendChild(i1);
```

I have tried to remove it like this but it does not work:

```
var floatingButton1 = document.getElementById('floatingButton1');
var i1 = document.createElement("img");
i1.src = "Images/whitesquare.png";
i1.type = "image";
floatingButton1.removeChild(i1);
```

How do I remove the image from the DIV / clear out all of the images I made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var floatingButton1 = document.getElementById('floatingButton1');
var i1 = document.createElement("img");
i1.src = "Images/whitesquare.png";
i1.type = "image";
```

The above code is not required in the second time. `var i1` already holds the reference  to the `image` appended.

Just use

```
floatingButton1.removeChild(i1);
```

Comment: If I try and use i1 in another function, it says that it is not defined. Does the variable go out of scope when I exit the function it was declared in?

Comment: then in the other function, get the reference of the ``element`` again, please share the code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) for specific response.

Comment: The variable goes out of scope when you exit the function it was declared in -- that is why i1 is not defined in the second function.  You need to pass i1 as a function parameter or define it outside the two functions.

Answer (score 1):

When you run

```
var i1 = document.createElement("img");
```

the second time, it creates a new `img` tag. To remove it all you need is

```
floatingButton1.removeChild(i1);
```

with out *any* of the other code in your second code block. None of that is necessary and when you redefine `i1` you've lost the reference entirely.